# Java, working in parallel on the same data

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing

the focus is on Java parallel threads. This post is not really a question, but a call for opinions and suggestions.
For some reason, I find hard to grab the way to make 2 parallel threads work on the same pool of data, in concurrency. I understand that Java is born to be a sound and robust language, and to avoid the dangers of using pointers, like C/C++ does. 
 
 
However, without pointers, doing some tasks like making parallel threads work together on the same data, requires some odd mind twists I don't fully grasp. 
In C/C++, you only have to pass pointers, and voila, the job is done.
 
 
Another constraint was to do all without the use of static variables and methods, because I find doing so, an easy escape.

Let's start...
I have a class Useless:

```
class Useless {
    private int a = 9;

    synchronized public void inc() {
    a++;
    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

What to do with Useless ? I instantiate it, inside another useless class.

```
class Inner extends Thread {
    private Useless useless1 = new Useless();

    @Override
    public void run() {
    useless1.inc();
    }
}
```

Now, the intuitive (but wrong) way to create 2 parallel threads that work on the same useless1 object is as follow:

```
public class Toexe2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Inner in1 = new Inner();
    Inner in2 = new Inner();

    in1.start();
    in2.start();
    }
}
```

The problem is clear: I have 2 instances of Inner and so 2 useless1 objects, each inside its Inner class. That doesn't work, so...

The simplest way to achieve my goal is to make an Outer class around Inner. Inner will be the runnable. But the Useless object, useless1, will have only 1 instance, as I want.
The complete file is this:

```
    package pk1;

    import pk1.Outer;
    import pk1.Useless;

    class Useless {
        private int a = 9;

        synchronized public void inc() {
        a++;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(a);
        }
    }

    class Outer {
        private Useless useless1 = new Useless();

        public class Inner extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            useless1.inc();
        }
        }
    }

    public class Toexe {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

        Outer st1 = new Outer();
        Outer.Inner in1 = st1.new Inner();
        Outer.Inner in2 = st1.new Inner();

        in1.start();
        in2.start();
        }
    }
```

My thoughts are: is there an even simplest way to achieve what I want to do, without using Inner classes ? 
The "everything is a class" paradigma of Java, make simple things to become very twisted and counterintuitive. Am I wrong ?

Comment: If you only want one `Useless` instance, make it a Singleton and be done with it.

Comment: [How to use a Singleton](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_singleton.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you are wrong. Java allows to program in C/C++ style.

First, not "everything is a class". A class with only static members is not a class, it is rather a source file in C. It is just a compilation unit as it was in Turbo Pascal.

Second, reference in Java is what pointer is in C/C++. It lacks some operations like increment/decrement or convertion to and from integer, but when passing as a parameter it is exactly a pointer, so if you know how to pass pointers in C/C++, do the same in Java.

Now how I would modify your code:

```
class Inner extends Thread {
    private Useless useless1;

    Inner(Useless useless1) {
         this.useless1 = useless1;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        useless1.inc();
    }
}

public class Toexe2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Useless useless1 = new Useless();

        Inner in1 = new Inner(useless1);
        Inner in2 = new Inner(useless1);

        in1.start();
        in2.start();
    }
}
```

Note `Inner` has not to be an inner class, it well can be an outer one.

Comment: @Mario Rossi you can thank by upvoting and accepting the answer :)